# How can I set docker affinity in docker correctly?

Tags: docker, affinity, cpu-cores

I want to limit the number of cores that a docker container uses.

I have found [the documentation](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-limit-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-docker-containers-a024b429f55e) and I can see that I can use `--cpus` as in

```
docker run -it --cpus=".5" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

but I don't understand what this setting actually represents. In the documentation example  it uses `0.5` which indicates 50% of the CPU (so a percentage)

however [in this other example](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-limit-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-docker-containers-a024b429f55e) it uses the command

```
--cpus=2
```

to set "the maximum number of CPUs that a container can use. For example, to limit a container to using two CPUs"

so which is which? a percentage or not

In my case for example I have a workstation of **X** cores and I want to limit it to **Y** cores. What should I put?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ :

> --cpus=
> Specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use. For instance, if the host machine has two CPUs and
> you set --cpus="1.5", the container is guaranteed at most one and a
> half of the CPUs. This is the equivalent of setting
> --cpu-period="100000" and --cpu-quota="150000".
> --cpu-period=
> Specify the CPU CFS scheduler period, which is used alongside --cpu-quota. Defaults to 100000 microseconds (100
> milliseconds). Most users do not change this from the default. For
> most use-cases, --cpus is a more convenient alternative.
> --cpu-quota=
> Impose a CPU CFS quota on the container. The number of microseconds per --cpu-period that the container is limited
> to before throttled. As such acting as the effective ceiling. For most
> use-cases, --cpus is a more convenient alternative.

`--cpus` specifies `--cpu-quota` which specifies the maximum cpu *time* the container will get per some period.

Also https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/glommer/memcg/+/cpu_stat/Documentation/cgroups/cpu.txt .

> cpu.cfs_quota_us [..]
> One should note that this represents aggregate time over all CPUs
> in the system. Therefore, in order to allow full usage of two CPUs, for
> instance, one should set this value to twice the value of cfs_period_us.

Effectively, setting `--cpus=2` will set `--cpu-quote = 2 * --cpu-period` which means that each 100 milliseconds the process will be maximally able to use 200 milliseconds on all cores, which effectively limits it to 2 cores.

> so which is which?

Both. A "core" is a virtual CPU. CPU here represents a core if your computer has like one cpu with many cores.

> What should I put?

`--cpus=Y` or `--cpuset-cpus=0-Y`.

Comment: Thanks! I have been recommended that it would be preferable to use `--cpuset-cpus` for this. Some advice on this would be appreciated

Comment: `Some advice` They do different things. Use a hammer when you want hammer a nail.